# SpringApplication.class missing in the gs-accessing-data-jpa-0.1.0.jar target jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am using Maven.  Pom is attached below.  Starter application from spring-boot page on Spring Source.  Application.java imports SpringApplication which it doesn't find.
The Pom includes necessary (i believe; must be wrong) spring-boot dependencies to download it all...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-accessing-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

END OF POM.

The generated target jar has spring-boot related packages, **but the org.springframework.boot package, which contains the `SpringApplication.class` among others is MISSING**.  Here's a snapshot of jar -tvf

```
317609 Mon Jul 14 10:10:28 PDT 2014 lib/spring-boot-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
341668 Mon Jul 14 10:10:28 PDT 2014 lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
  2183 Mon Jul 14 10:10:28 PDT 2014 lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
  2139 Mon Jul 14 10:10:28 PDT 2014 lib/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
  2267 Mon Jul 14 10:10:28 PDT 2014 lib/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
  **2169 Mon Jul 14 10:10:28 PDT 2014 lib/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
  2177 Mon Jul 14 10:10:28 PDT 2014 lib/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
     0 Mon Jul 14 10:10:28 PDT 2014 org/springframework/boot/
     0 Mon Jul 14 10:10:28 PDT 2014 org/springframework/boot/loader/
  1722 Tue Jul 08 02:17:24 PDT 2014 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$ArchiveEntryFilter.class**
  1967 Tue Jul 08 02:17:24 PDT 2014 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
```

Notice the org/springframework/boot followed by NO classes, then on to package org.springframework/boot/loader...

what am I missing please?

Comment: FOUND the answer.  Should have run: mvn spring-boot:run... and it did work.  (can't post answer yet - <10 reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn spring-boot:run` 
instead of

```
mvn clean install
```

Did and works.

`Spring Boot`'s a great project; also using `Spring-Data`. Equally great - love the JPA abstraction supporting SQL and NoSQL (Mongo) DBs with very similar semantics!!

A bit of a concern however is: Every new Spring framework project is taking us further away from the 'under-the-hood' things, that I am afraid whether we are adding too many layers of abstraction where value-to-clarity ratio keeps goes down.